# Bike chain making clicking noise when pedaling (both when pedaling hard and easy)

Tags: chain, noise, road

The bike is making a clicking noise when I sit on it and pedal. The problem is a lot less obvious when I put it up and try to spin the crank, but when I try to spin the crank with some resistance created by rear brake sometimes I can reproduce a similar noise (not sure if it’s the same one). The one I could reproduce is that the chain seems to “snap” onto the chain wheel consistently on a certain part, as of it’s not smoothly going onto the wheel tooth, but jumps onto it - and it’s only on that part of chain. I have a video of it:

I also checked brakes and derailleurs, front derailleur is not switching properly but it’s also not touching the chain in any case. Chain tension also seems fine, as I can’t pull out chain without moving the tension gear. What could be the problem?

P.S. My bike is a bikesdirect Windsor tourist FB.

P.S. I rode about 160 miles on the bike and haven't cleaned it (ik it's bad) so I'm also open to maintenance tips and product recommendations

Comment: You can upload the video to any of the common web platforms and then link to it.

Comment: thanks andy! I added a link.